# Volley JSON request only returning first two values

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i have a json file hosted -> http://cipherads.co.in/api/bbps/billerinfo.php

i need to fetch all the "billerId" fields. I am using Volley to make the GET request and loop over the object. But i am facing an issue, my log shows only first two "billerId" values. How can i fix this ?

```
    String urlJsonObj = "http://cipherads.co.in/api/bbps/billerinfo.php";

    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

    //showpDialog();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONArray biller = response.getJSONArray("biller");
                Log.d(TAG, biller.toString());

                // Loop through biller Array and find billerID
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject billerID = (JSONObject) biller.get(i);
                    String id = billerID.getString("billerId");
                    Log.d(TAG, id);


                }


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), biller.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < biller.length(); i++)
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can i know what was i doing wrong?

Comment: I think no problem with Volley. Volley and Retrofit they work differently for network calling. Priority is with whom you fell comfort..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here
`for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)`

You are checking you JSONobject's size giving 2 in your case. 
Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < biller.length(); i++)
```

To iterate through your JSONArray's size instead.

Edit: Noticed an answer was already posted after I added this, decided to leave it here anyway incase you needed a bit of explanation related to it.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Ca i know what was i doing wrong? Also do u suggest using Retrofit instead of volley ?

Comment: Well, that was the reason I undeleted my answer, anyway, in your case ```response``` is  the JSON Object for complete response received, which will have length as 2 for the 2 keys in the json response you get "responseCode" and "biller". This biller is the JSONArray you need values of, so when using for loop you need the complete length of "biller" array contained inside the object not no. of keys in response object itself. As for which is better its simply opinion based [check this perhaps](https://medium.com/@sudhakarprajapati7/retrofit-vs-volley-c6cf74b3c8e4). Hope this was understandable

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue. I will go through the link.